# editing values in a dictionary saved in a file

Tags: python

I am making a text-based game as a challenge project and have been tasked to save the users progress I've managed to save the name, position, inventory so when I play again I'm able to load previous progress; the problem comes the third time I try to load it was it will load the progress of the previous (first) playthrough. The progress is saved in a dictionary saved to a file I wish to save the changes made in the current playthrough by editing values of the dictionary already saved in the file instead of adding unusable data.

```
def save(name):
    file = open("save_game.txt","a+")
    saved["Name"] = name
    file.write(str(saved) + "\n")
    file.close()


def position(positions):
    file = open("save_game.txt","a+")
    saved["Position"] = positions
    file.write(str(saved))
    file.close()
```

this is the code to save name and position of user
this is the output into the file on the first playthrough:*{'Name': 'Name', 'Position': 1}*
this is the game when loaded with this first playthrough on the second playthrough:

- ==================welcome====================

==================LEVEL 1 : Escape====================

You are at the front corridor of a house

> - 

this is position one so this is good
now I will change position on the second playthrough
*This is the basement stairs

> - 

this is position 3
this is output into the file after I save the second playthrough
*{'Name': 'Name', 'Position': 1}
{'Position': 3}*
this will not allow me to continue from the second playthrough on my third playthrough
this is load in on my third playthrough:

- ==================welcome====================

==================LEVEL 1 : Escape====================

You are at the front corridor of a house

> - 

bad; this is my save on the first playthrough
I need to change the value of the position in the file every playthrough. Pls, help.

Comment: Writing a string representation of a dict is not an appropriate way to serialize a dictionary to a file, but what you are asking is a more general question about how to save some program state to a file and restore it and there are many, many existing questions about this.  Have you looked around a bit and still not found what you are looking for?

Comment: yes I have but what i need to do is change a value within the file during the moment the user saves and exits the

Comment: Python dictionary has a shape that's close to JSON, so you may try saving it as JSON.

Comment: How does the user save and exit the game?  At that point you would re-write the file, or even occasionally while the game is running.

Comment: what about another user

Comment: Encapsulate relevant data in a Python class then pickle (serialise) that object. See:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: ill check it out thanks